# VBA user form: populating refedit range into listbox (showing each identical answer only once)

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am very new to Excel VisualBasic.

Previously, I have only used it for some simple macros and this is my first question here.

I am trying to create a user form for the first time and have refedit boxes where ranges can be selected.

I want to be able to take the selected range from a refedit box to auto-populate into a listbox, which should then show identical answers from the refedit precisely once.

Example

If "male" is in the refedit range 10 times, it should only be shown once in the listbox.

In the listbox I then only want to choose (i.e. click) one of these values to be used.

The name of the first refedit box is refedit1 and the listbox I want to associate with it is `Firstcriteriaselect`.

The only code I have in the userform currently is to show a separate label caption for the first cell of the refedit range chosen for ease of use:

My VB code is as follows:

```
Private Sub refedit1_change()

Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range(Me.RefEdit1.Value).Cells(1)
Labelfirst1.Caption = rng1
End Sub
```

I have created the code above seven times for seven refedit boxes.

Apologies if any of this unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array (or collection) as a buffer between cell values in the RefEdit range which would contain only unique values. You can add items to that array by comparing each new one with items already in the array. Then you can populate your listbox from that array.